# cmake: Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR)

Tags: windows, cmake, libcurl

I'm on windows 10 and I want to use [curlpp](http://www.curlpp.org/) library. The building of [curlpp](http://www.curlpp.org/) depends on the availability of `curl` and `curl` is by default present in my system but when i try to run the cmake, it gives the following output

```
    -- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 to target Windows 10.0.19043.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30145.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30145.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- curlpp version=[0.8.1]
-- curlpp version num=[000801]
-- Looking for CURL
-- Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR)
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindCURL.cmake:181 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:60 (find_package)
```

Here is the `CmakeLists.txt` of [curlpp](http://www.curlpp.org/)

```
project(curlpp) 


# In response to CMake 3.0 generating warnings regarding policy CMP0042,
# the OSX RPATH settings have been updated per recommendations found
# in the CMake Wiki:
#  http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling#Mac_OS_X_and_the_RPATH
if(POLICY CMP0042)
    cmake_policy(SET CMP0042 NEW) # MACOSX_RPATH
    set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH TRUE)
endif()

# for unix platform, define install directories.
include(GNUInstallDirs)

if(WIN32)
    # cmake 3.4 is required for CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)

    # c++ 11 support from cmake 3.4 or newer
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11) # C++11...
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON) #...is required...
    set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF) #...without compiler extensions like gnu++11

    set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)
  else()
    if (${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 3.1)
        cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
        # c++11 support for cmake 2.8.12 - 3.0.x
        #
        # for non-windows platform we try to keep cmake 2.8 support
        # since entreprise distribution tends to have 2.8 version.
        add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
    else()
        # c++ 11 support from cmake 3.1 or newer
        set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11) # C++11...
        set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON) #...is required...
        set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF) #...without compiler extensions like gnu++11
    endif()
endif()


# Conan.io integration
if(EXISTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
    include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
    conan_basic_setup()
endif()

# extra (pkg-config-related files)
add_subdirectory(extras)

#########################################################################################
# Look for dependencies

# Documented at https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindCURL.html?highlight=curlpp
# Seems simple.

message(STATUS "Looking for CURL")
include(FindCURL)
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)

if(CURL_FOUND)
  message(STATUS "Found CURL version: ${CURL_VERSION_STRING}")
  message(STATUS "Using CURL include dir(s): ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
  message(STATUS "Using CURL lib(s): ${CURL_LIBRARIES}")
else()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find CURL")
endif()

# All following targets should search these directories for headers
include_directories( 
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
  ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

#########################################################################################
# Define Targets

# If building on windows, install path will be in build/winbuild
if(CMAKE_SYSTEM MATCHES "Windows")
   set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "winbuild")
endif()

file(GLOB_RECURSE HeaderFileList "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*")
file(GLOB_RECURSE SourceFileList "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*")
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${HeaderFileList} ${SourceFileList})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CURL_LIBRARIES} ${CONAN_LIBS})
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES SOVERSION 1 VERSION 1.0.0)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}_static STATIC ${HeaderFileList} ${SourceFileList})

# Make sure that on unix-platforms shared and static libraries have
# the same root name, but different suffixes.
#
#  (solution taken from https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_do_I_make_my_shared_and_static_libraries_have_the_same_root_name.2C_but_different_suffixes.3F)
# 
# Making shared and static libraries have the same root name, but different suffixes
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${PROJECT_NAME}_static PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
# Now the library target "curlpp_static" will be named "curlpp.lib" with MS tools.
# This conflicts with the "curlpp.lib" import library corresponding to "curlpp.dll",
# so we add a "lib" prefix (which is default on other platforms anyway):
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${PROJECT_NAME}_static PROPERTIES PREFIX "lib")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_static ${CURL_LIBRARIES} ${CONAN_LIBS})

# install headers
install(DIRECTORY include/utilspp/ DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/utilspp")
install(DIRECTORY include/curlpp/ DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/curlpp")

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME}_static
        RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
```

I've also downloaded [curl from GitHub](https://github.com/curl/curl) and had successfully build it but i don't know how to tell the cmake to find the `curl`
Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: How and where have you **installed** Curl on your machine? It seems that CMake isn't aware about that installation, so you need to hint CMake about it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: I don't know how to "hint CMake" to find the curl, that's what i'm looking for

Comment: For hint CMake about the Curl installation one need to know **location** of that installation. But you seem to ignore the first sentence of my previous comment: "How and where have you installed Curl?"

Comment: @Tsyvarev: I've installed Curl on my Desktop, the path is "Desktop\curl\build\src\Release\". 
I've installed it using the cmake command and then build the .sln in VS19, it successfully build i.e. "curl.exe", "libcurl.dll" and "libcurl_imp.lib" is now present on the above path

Comment: I've passed the "-DCURL_LIBRARY" and "-DCURL_INCLUDE_DIR" flags along the path to cmake, and it build it successfully. thank you.